xorg.conf adding odd values at boot in Ubuntu 24 with nvidia 535 driver
Ubuntu 24.04 new install. Nvidia driver 535.171.04
xorg.conf isn't a new topic, and it's eternally frustrating...
I am defining this metamode in my xorg.conf file "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select @2560x1440 +0+1022 {ViewPortIn=2560x1440, ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1440x2560 +2560+0 {ViewPortIn=1440x2560, ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0, Rotation=90}"
If I use nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode= with that line, my monitors set the way I have defined.
Yet, at boot, the rotation does not occur and the syslog indicates that it tried the metamode but decided it wasn't valid:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0):     "DVI-D-0:2560x1440@2560x1440+0+1022{ViewPortIn=2560x1440,ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0},HDMI-0:2560x1440@1440x2560+2560+0{ViewPortIn=1440x2560,ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0,Rotation=90}";
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0):     removing.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Unable to validate any modes; falling back to the default mode
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0):     "nvidia-auto-select".
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1840]: (WW) NVIDIA(G0):

I could easily work around this problem, but would like to understand what is going on. Why isn't the metamode valid at boot? It's pretty specific that the problem is the mode, but here is the xorg Screen section
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "DVI-D-0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: 2560x1440 @2560x1440 +0+1022 {ViewPortIn=2560x1440, ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0}, HDMI-0: 2560x1440 @1440x2560 +2560+0 {ViewPortIn=1440x2560, ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0, Rotation=90}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "TwinView" "true"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
#    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "true"
#    Option         "IgnoreEDID" "true"
#    Option         "UseEdidFreqs" "false"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

